# Ruby Grape rescue_from :all not rescuing all errors

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape

My Grape app has several error handlers, including lastly:

```
rescue_from :all, backtrace: true do |e|
  message = { errors: { all: e.message } }
  rack_response(format_message(message, e.backtrace), 500 )
end
```

But this is not rescuing at least errors that Grape processes with

```
throw :error
```

internally. How do I rescue those errors? The particular errors noted are "The requested format 'txt' is not supported" and "Not Found: some_path". These errors occur when the format extension is missing or only a '.' is supplied, respectively.

Comment: Is it Rails question ?

Comment: No. Rails is not used.

Answer (score 1):

You don't rescue the thrown conditions. They will go straight to the error handler, because `rescue` is for `raise`d errors, not thrown conditions. `throw` does not create exactly the same objects as `raise`, and cannot be processed in the same way.

You could however, *format* the error message using an `error_formatter`:

```
module CustomErrorFormatter
  def self.call message, backtrace, options, env
     { errors: { all: message.to_s } }.to_json
  end
end
```

And in the main app:

```
error_formatter :json, CustomErrorFormatter
```

Comment: I thought that Grape might catch the thrown errors and Raise a Grape::Exception to unify the interface.

Comment: The Grape formatters assume a format extension and the two errors mentioned are because the format extension is missing (question edited). Using a default format handles the first case of no format extension, but the second of just a '.' still fails and sends text since there is no format by which to select a custom formatter.

Comment: @Geroge Shaw: I may be behind the times regarding raising Grape::Exception, or there may be a good reason in terms of internals to now re-direct in this way, I don't know. Are you using e.g. `default_error_formatter :json`?

Comment: Tried that and it did not solve the problem. Looking closer, Grape returns a 404, and sees, I think, that it can't find a matching route. A comment in the Grape source on 'cascade?' I think applies here. I need to look at if our app can not cascade and how to do that.

Comment: 404 . . . Grape may not be processing those. They may coming direct from Rack. If so, you may be able to add a catch-all route at the end of the listing, so that Grape is handling them.